# Proper way to animate a loop in Javascript- Should I use Vue or a library like Anime.js?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, frontend, anime.js

I am working on a looping animation modifying the background of a web page. Right now, I have built it with Vue by modifying a variable in Vue's data object bound to a style tag of the page I'm working on. This work's but it's a bit messy and doesn't seem like I am using Vue as intended. I'm wondering if it is better technique to import a library like anime.js or else to use a css animation? Is it overkill/ bad technique to import anime or to load Vue for light animations? What is the rule of thumb with this sort of thing?

Comment: What kind of animation is it? Have you got an example? And if you can avoid using libraries and use the browsers built in optimised systems, prefer those.

Comment: Basically, it's a gradient background which slowly changes color and rotates. I promise it looks better and more modern than it sounds.

Answer (score -1):

You are using simple animations then you can try the `List-Transitions` in VueJS.

Link: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#List-Transitions

Comment: Thanks, that's a really great feature to know, but I'm not sure if it will work well in this case. Unless I'm misunderstanding, that feature is for temporary transitions not continuous animation loops.